# Scale images to be full viewport height without cutting off part of the image

Tags: html, css

So what I'm trying to achieve is the following style

[image: Mockup]

Essentially it's three different photos

Big picture on the left as well as two rectangle pictures on the right.

The problem I'm having is i need these to fill 100 view port when you visit so I put

```
.intro-deals{
  height: calc(100vh - 182px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

which does fill the pages view port but the images will get cut off. and look like the following:

[image: Actual]

You can see how the image will get cutoff at the bottom, What would be the best way to approach this?

Here is the main part of my code as well

```
<div className="intro-deals">
  <div className="col-md-6 no-pad">
    <a href=""><img className="img-responsive" src={require('../images/home/header/Home_bannerMain.jpg')} alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6 no-pad">
    <a href=""><img className="img-responsive" src={require('../images/home/header/Home_bannerSide1.jpg')} alt=""/></a>
    <a href=""><img className="img-responsive" src={require('../images/home/header/Home_bannerSide2.jpg')} alt=""/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.intro-deals{
  height: calc(100vh - 182px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

## Edit

Also a simplified [Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/EWxpoE) (You will have to view in full-screen mode)

Comment: Tagged as css, but showing scss ?

Comment: My bad @saj removed the scss both are acceptable for me is what i was trying to portray

Comment: Nice!, i'd have a go at that if you dropped a fiddle or a pen friend and so would a fair few others

Comment: @saj set up a minified codepen:)

Comment: Part(s) of the image(s) will get cropped unless you don't care about maintaining their natural dimensions/proportions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture (before seeing the code), the best shot I thought to achieve this was:

1. Setting up height/width of all boxes according to viewport
2. Using images as backgrounds for divs, with `background-size: cover`, and `background-position: center center`.

That's it